# Defence agaisnt X martial art type question

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

Based on the question [Defence agaisnt Wing Chun](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/2802/82). Are we really going to allow questions of this type on this site?

Answer (score 2):

I see it as a [gorilla vs shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) thus not really answerable.

If we are to allow it under the guise of "what are the weaknesses of martial art X?", then we invite long lists, fiction, and rants that will ultimately serve little purpose and degenerate into flame wars.  Shockingly enough, I am proven right once more...

Answer (score 2):

If the question consisted of just the first sentence then it would definitely be off topic. As you mention it's Gorilla vs. Shark, and this sort of question was also explicitly discussed and agreed as off topic during the Area 51 proposal stage.

However.... the OP has gone on to clarify the question and to narrow the scope. Different people would read the question in different ways, which is why it has attracted a couple of good answers. It is certainly an *answerable* question, it just remains to be seen whether it can answered definitively (or close to it).

In any case it is up to the community to decide whether to close it, and that is exactly what is happening with three close votes cast so far. As a mod I stay out of it because it's a community decision.

If it does get closed then it may also get reopened again - it is normal to have this sort of factional disagreement. My philosophy is that if I vote to close, the question gets closed, then gets voted open again then I shrug and accept it - unless it is truly awful then I'll vote to close again.

My advice: use the voting tools at your disposal, and sit back and watch.